# How does promise linking work in Scala and why is it necessary?

Tags: scala, promise, garbage-collection, future

I found some some articles and the source code of Scala's futures and promises:

- https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-9.html
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala
- Current implementation with a big comment explaining the promise linking: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala
- Stress test which leads to memory exhaustion without promise linking: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/test/files/run/t7336.scala

but I still do not really understand how the promise linking really works.
First of all, the memory exhaustion stress test references big arrays in the callbacks.
These should cause the big arrays to stay in memory until the callbacks have been executed?

I have tried to write a scenario of the stress test in pseudo code.

Example by showing a call with i = 3:

```
x4 = call3

call3 = {
    val array3 = new BigArray
    val f3 = Future { 3 }
    x3 = f3.flatMap( 3 => array3; call2 )

    return x3
}

call2 = {
    val array2 = new BigArray
    val f2 = Future { 2 }

    x2 = f2.flatMap( 2 => array2; call1 )

    return x2
}

call1 = {
    val array1 = new BigArray
    val f1 = Future { 1 }

    x1 = f1.flatMap( 1 => array1; call0 )

    return x1
}

call0 = {
    val array0 = new BigArray
    val f0 = Future { 0 }

    x0 = f0.flatMap( 0 => Future.succesful() )

    return x0
}
```

Usually, x0, x1, x2 and x3 would be triggered when f0, f1, f2 and f3 are completed and then would call their function, for example:

```
1 => array1; call0
```

so it would call `x1.completeWith(call0)` which basically is `x1.completeWith(x0)`.

This would lead to the following chain:

```
x4.completeWith(x3)
x3.completeWith(x2)
x2.completeWith(x1)
x1.completeWith(x0)
x0.completeWith(Future.successful())
```

From my understanding, since all calls lead to the same result, they can be linked like:

```
x4.completeWith(Future.successful())
```

As long as all callbacks from x0, x1, x2 and x3 are moved to x4.
All futures/promises become identical?

Now, how does the promise linking behave exactly in Scala 2.13.xx?
Is x4 the root which waits for the other futures to be completed?
Are the other futures/promises now converted into Link[T]?
The method `linkRootOf` in the Scala 2.13.xx implementation seems to create a new link to the target and store it in the state of the future/promise.
It replaces its callbacks by it.
The callbacks are moved to the root future/promise target to be executed when the root future/promise is completed?
This happens when f0 is completed.

Even if there is a chain of links to the root future/promise, I don't get why it does not leak anymore?

The references of the big arrays are accessed when f0, f1, f2 and f3 are completed since then the callbacks are executed.
But isn't this the time when the links are created, so the references are already gone now? `completeWith` should be none blocking, so the arrays could be released, even without creating a link?

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has answered this question yet, I will try to answer it by myself.
I have asked in the Scala forum about promise linking and got an explanation: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-does-promise-linking-work/3326

From my understanding it only works when the promises/futures are identical as I suspected

The memory exhaustion with the array reference in a closure not being released by the garbage collection was just a bug in the Scala compiler. Therefore, the whole optimization is some kind of over engineering because of this bug.
I couldn't reproduce the memory exhaustion with the latest Scala version.

However, reducing the chain length will work with promise linking and therefore there will be less promises if they are identical but since a promise should not take that much memory the optimization is not really necessary. I couldn't find a use case of that many nested `flatMap` calls.

From what I have read in the Scala FP and the Twitter Util implementations for the example I have posted in my question the links would be produced the following way:

```
x4.completeWith(x3) // x3 becomes a link to x4 and moves all of its callback to x4
x3.completeWith(x2) // x2 becomes a link to x3. Since x3 is a link to x4, all the callbacks are moved to x4. When the compression of the chain takes place it is directly linked to x4, so x3 can be released by the garbage collection since there is no reference to it anymore.
x2.completeWith(x1) // x1 becomes a link to x2 and by compression directly to x4
x1.completeWith(x0) // x0 becomes a link to x1 and by compression directly to x4
x0.completeWith(Future.successful()) // the passed future completes x0 since it is already completed and since x0 is a link to x4 it will actually complete x4 and all callbacks will be submitted to the underlying executor
```

The compression of the chain of links allows releasing the link elements earlier by the garbage collection since they are not referred anywhere anymore.
This means that you have less promises in the memory.
There will always be only `x4` and one link to it.
The callbacks are collected in the root promise/future `x4`.
We would have to assume that `x3`, `x2`, `x1` and `x0` have some callbacks registered before the `tryCompleteWith` call.
Otherwise, nothing will be moved.